# Unknown user error when trying to set up replication with informix

Tags: informix, cdr

I am on a linux system, logged in as the informix user. I have the following environment variables set:

```
INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix
INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/opt/IBM/informix/etc/sqlhosts.mydb
INFORMIXSERVER=rep_0
```

The contents of sqlhosts.mydb are as follows:

```
g_rep_0         group           -               -       i=0
rep_0           onsoctcp        svr0            30100   g=g_rep_0

g_rep_1         group           -               -       i=1
rep_1           olsoctcp        svr1            30101   g=g_rep_1
```

I am trying to run the command `cdr define server --init g_rep_0` to set up g_rep_0 as the replication master, but get the following error:

```
connect to rep_0 failed 
Incorrect password or user rep_0 is not known on the database server.
 (-951)
command failed -- unable to connect to server specified  (5)
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

**edit**

Looking in the log I got an error:

```
10:26:36  CDR GC: operation error reporting severe error message failed (error 62).
10:30:00  SCHAPI: [Save SQL Trace 27-550] Error -206 The specified table (mon_syssqltrace) is not in the database.
10:30:00  SCHAPI: [Save SQL Trace 27-550] Error -111 ISAM error:  no record found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be due to a corrupt database. I re-initialized it by running `onmode -ky`, `oninit -ivyw`, and it appears to be fine now.

Comment: Difficult to decide what to do with this.  That is an unusual reason for the failure; most people won't run across the problem.  Your answer clearly is correct and helpful in your scenario, but...